# Rendering with Nvidia Grid

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been playing with an online service [paperspace.io](http://paperspace.io) they do cloud computers. I was hoping to render on their computers when I only have access to my laptop.

They use Nvidia Grid cards and I can't see the Cuda option in the blender settings. I've installed the Cuda drivers etc.

Just wondered if it's even possible to render on Nvidia Grid cards?

Thanks

Comment: According to [this Blender Artists post](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480-2-7x-Cycles-benchmark-(Updated-BMW)&p=2487669&viewfull=1#post2487669) it seems to be supported, but it's probably badly optimized since it's an unusual setup. Are you trying to pre-set up NVidia Grids while working locally from your laptop? That would obviously be unavailable since the cards are lodged only on the server, not directly in the laptop

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Paperspace is kind of like Virtual box but just online. You just load it up like a normal windows computer. I think it's got an Nvidia Grid k160, which I know are shared graphics cards. I think they're going to have dedicated Quadro's in the next week or so so I'll probably just wait for then. - thanks :)

Comment: Being a virtual computer there may not be a dedicated gpu for each instance, so Blender may not be able to see the card as being available. Also if you are running blender locally on your laptop it would obviously not be able to see the remote virtual cards

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah i think it's because it's a virtual computer. I wasn't going to run Blender on the laptop, only the virtual computer, that way it's doing all the heavy work and the laptop isn't

Comment: I vaguely remember hearing this in a YouTube video. From my understanding you can't. I don't remember what the video was called, but it was a general how to explanation video about Blender. I can try looking in my history

Comment: @KyraToomey yeahI don't think you can. I ended up building a pc with a couple of decent nvidia cards instead. Seems to work well for me now :)